# stop pop up and other notification windows from a Web Browser Control

Tags: c#, com, browser, webbrowser-control, mshtml

I created a c# web browser but I wanted to block the scrips and other notification (like, while navigating to other page we get pop up windows asking "Are you sure want to leave the page")...

I handled the scrips but pop up windows still comes.

I tried with `AxWebBrowser` and worked with `NewWindows2` `newWindow3` events nut nothing is working....

Any idea how to disable any other kind of windows on web browsers? 
Or
if it come how to close it automatic?

**Edit1**: Pop up windows are coming from JavaScript.

Comment: You cannot suppress javascript alert() popups without disabling scripting completely.

Comment: suppressing is possible... but any way to stop alert or any pop ups

Comment: FYI, "JavaScript" is one word - it has nothing to do with the Java programming language.

Comment: Ok... forget about js, can we know, is there any child windows(tat will be pop windows) for web browser??

Comment: Did you set the Silent flag for the control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [client site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693706%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can provide the [IDocHostShowUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753269%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface and MSHTML will call your [ShowMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753271%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method for JavaScript [alerts and confirms](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp). There you can decide whether you want to display your own UI or use the default handling. Just pretend you display something by returning `S_OK` and no message box appears.

As a positive side effect you get information about all message box parameters (including type and text), so you could make a finer grade decision based on them.